# Cannot update global variable within addeventListener function

Tags: html, typescript, event-listener

Basically when running `addEventListener` I cannot access any of my saved variables from outside the function I am creating.

In the following code I always get the error `Property 'xAxisLabel' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

```
xAxisLabel:string = 'xAxis';
xAxisField:HTMLElement;

filterChanged(element: HTMLElement) {
   element.addEventListener("change", function(){
      this.xAxisLabel = 'Countries';
   });
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.xAxisField=document.getElementById('xAxisField');
   this.filterChanged(this.xAxisField);
}
```

I am sure it's a fairly simple solution but I haven't been able to find it online. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Been a while since I did HTML stuff. Isn't xAxisLabel defined on 'window' instead of the HTML element? Can you use a breakpoint somewhere to verify what object that label-property belongs to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is due to 'this' keyword binding. You need to change your code to use arrow function, so:

```
 filterChanged(element: HTMLElement) {
   element.addEventListener("change", () => {
      this.xAxisLabel = 'Countries';
   });
}
```

now this.xAxisLabel refers to correct value

Comment: Yes perfect thank you. My typescript experience was a little lacking in that department I'm afraid XD